# A link to local html file in r vignette

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package

Is there a way to include a link to a local .html file to my package vignette in R?

I'm writing a vignette to a package, ad i want to include a link to my previous research. This research is saved as an .html file, but a can't host it anywhere do to safety restrictions. So I created a \inst directory, so that this files are delivered with the package. But if i provide a link as usual, it doesn't work

```
the more details are in this [research](./inst/research/research.html)

URL '/help/library/packagename/doc/inst//research/research.html' not found
```

Comment: Are you planning on distributing your package in any way? Because if you can't host your file anywhere due to safety restrictions (what do you mean by this?), hard to see how you could put your package up on (for example) CRAN if it includes your research as a file.

Comment: The compony've got its own repo, So it Will be for enternal use only.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Have you tried `../inst/research/research.html` instead of `./inst/research/research.html`?

Comment: Yeh, didn't help. After the packages is installed, the data is in program files/r/library/research/reasearch.html. But hardcoding the pass didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Documents in `./inst/research` will be installed in the package directory under `./research` (everything in `./inst` is [moved one level up during installation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html)).
You can get the package installation directory with `find.package`.
So you could create the link in the vignette by including following code in Markdown :

```
[research](`r paste0('file:///',file.path(find.package('NameOfPackage'),'research','research.html'))`)
```

Please note that links don't work in RStudio Viewer, so please try in Browser, after installation of the package.
This should work for packages installed from source.

Comment: I've put my htmls to inst/research. And pass a link in my .rmd this way:
[research]('r paste("file://", .libpaths()[length(.libpaths)], "packname", "research", "research.html", sep = "/")').
As a result, the link is right, but it won't open on click, if i do right click and choose "open in a New tab", i See the link, but the documents won' t render until i select the adress and press enter.

Comment: Everithing is works fine if i open the vignette from the folder, but if i open them with the browseVignette(), i'll have that strange behavior.

Comment: I forgot to include the file:/// I had in mind in my first post. Can you try with the updated version?

Comment: Great thanks to you for your answer! I used .libpaths and the last output of it, becouse your set of function was directing us to some temp folder, maybe they are created while the packages is building, i dont know. Maybe you know why the link is unklickable when the vignette is called via BrowseVignette function?

Comment: I also don't have yet an explaination for BrowseVignette...

Comment: The thing is that the browseVignette host the vignette localy, on 127.0.0.1:10072  in my case. So it treats the html not as if it is a local file, but a hosted one. If there is a way to put files from inst/ to doc/ while building the pakage, that would help a lot.